# haraka: MX without A records

Tags: node.js, email

I write a plugin to forward some email  to another email according database.

the code simplest like the following:

```
exports.hook_rcpt = function (next, connection, params) {
var rcpt = params[0];

    if (rcpt.host == "xxx.com") {
        it.logwarn("====skdlf");
        var address = // get address from database according rcpt.user
        var toAddress = new Address('<' + address + '>');
    connection.transaction.rcpt_to.pop();
    connection.transaction.rcpt_to.push(toAddress);
    connection.relaying = true
    next(OK);
    return;
    }
   next(DENYSOFT, "not found user account");
}
```

but, it seem the server never run into any code in the above.
and i get the following error :

```
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8] [access] pass:unlisted(conn)
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any
[ERROR] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8] [dnsbl] no zones
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any, helo:any
[ERROR] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8] [helo.checks] forward_dns(Error: queryA ESERVFAIL smtpbg63.qq.com.)
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8.1] [access] pass:unlisted(mail)
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8.1] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any, helo:any, mf/rt:any
[INFO] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8.1] [core] hook=mail plugin=mail_from.is_resolvable function=hook_mail params="<xxxxxxx@qq.com>" retval=DENY msg="MX without A records"
[NOTICE] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8.1] [core] sender <xxxxxx@qq.com> code=DENY msg="MX without A records"
[NOTICE] [38A98778-D1E0-4064-AF11-0A54720063A8.1] [core] disconnect ip=103.7.29.150 rdns="smtpbg63.qq.com" helo="smtpbg63.qq.com" relay=N early=N esmtp=Y tls=N pipe=N txns=1 rcpts=0/0/0 msgs=0/0/0 bytes=0 lr="550 MX without A records" time=10.166
[NOTICE] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [core] connect ip=14.17.32.37 port=38176 local_ip=:: local_port=25
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [access] pass:unlisted(conn)
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any
[ERROR] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [dnsbl] no zones
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any, helo:any
[ERROR] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A] [helo.checks] forward_dns(Error: queryA ESERVFAIL smtpbg326.qq.com.)
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A.1] [access] pass:unlisted(mail)
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A.1] [access] pass:unlisted(conn), connect:any, helo:any, mf/rt:any
[INFO] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A.1] [core] hook=mail plugin=mail_from.is_resolvable function=hook_mail params="<xxxxxxxxxx@qq.com>" retval=DENY msg="MX without A records"
[NOTICE] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A.1] [core] sender <xxxxxx@qq.com> code=DENY msg="MX without A records"
[NOTICE] [5EE4F7EA-7003-4E28-80BC-26A0E0B1CB1A.1] [core] disconnect ip=14.17.32.37 rdns="smtpbg326.qq.com" helo="smtpbg326.qq.com" relay=N early=N esmtp=Y tls=N pipe=N txns=1 rcpts=0/0/0 msgs=0/0/0 bytes=0 lr="550 MX without A records" time=10.901
```

sorry for lack of the knowledge about email server, but what's the key point to solve the problem, I hope to create a forward server

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- First disable all the unnecessary plugins when you test your code
- Did you enable the plugin by adding the name to config/plugin?
- Use  `this.loginfo("Something");` to print to the console.
- Read this carefully https://haraka.github.io/manual/Tutorial.html